# MySQL How to get a column from a parameter passed from the URL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a mySQL database where the primary key is a string that is a username and a field is a URL. The username is passed through the url, and the url is printed out. However, I cant get the code to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Query string</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("na","na","na");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("na", $con); 
    $query="SELECT * FROM  `na`.`na` WHERE 'Username' = '" . $_GET["username"] . "'";
     $data = mysql_query($query) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
 { 
Print "URL>>".$info['Url'] . "URL>>" ; 
 } 
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your query is not working is because you have wrap the column named `Username` with single quotes. Remember that column name are identifier and not string literals. Wrapping identifiers with single quote makes it a string literal. So in your case you are comparing a value into a string `username` and not into a column name `username`. Remove the single quote and it will surely work.

```
SELECT * FROM  `na`.`na` WHERE Username = ''
```

Try this one out, pass a value in the `$_GET["username"]` with `Username` and you will get all the records in the table because `'Username' = 'Username'` which makes it always true.

- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)